# Show single data column in ASP.NET MVC 5 using Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Sorry if this question have exists.

I using ASP.NET MVC 5 + Entity Framework to build a project and I have a problem which not resolve.

In controller:

```
private NewsEntities db = new NewsEntities();

public ActionResult Index()
{
        var art = db.Articles.Where(m=>m.Id==1).Select(m => new { m.Id , m.NameArt}).ToList();
        return View(art);
}
```

And in view:

```
@model IEnumerable<DemoHC.Models.Article>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NameArt)
    </td>
<tr>
}
```

and I when build it in server then display error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.Int32,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DemoHC.Models.Article]'.

Can you help me and thanks pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is creating a collection of anonymous objects, not a collection of `Article` objects.

Change your code to

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var art = db.Articles.Where(m => m.Id == 1);
    return View(art);
}
```

or alternatively you could create a view model with just the properties you want

```
public class ArticleVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and change the query to

```
var art = db.Articles.Where(m => m.Id == 1).Select(m => new ArticleVM
{
    ID = m.Id,
    Name = m.NameArt
};
return View(art);
```

and the model in the view will then be

```
@model IEnumerable<ArticleVM>
```